# Finding nearest neighbors of a hexagon on the dual of a Goldberg Polyhedron

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, polyhedra, geodesic

For this question, though I'm looking for a generalized answer that works independent of size, the Goldberg Polyhedron that I have is $GP(2, 2)$

Its dual being a subdivided icosahedron of $\{3,5+\}_{2,2}$

The hexagons are labelled using the axial coordinate system.

Is there a way to find the barycentric coordinates of the 3 nearest neighboring hexagons when some of those hexagons are across the icosahedron face boundary?

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPYNr.jpg)

The example image is a face of a GP(2,2), as well as edges of its dual. One hexagon has a neighbor across the face boundary and one hexagon, is itself, across the face boundary. Getting the coordinates for those hexagons is the problem.

[$\{3,5+\}_{2, 2}$ icosahedron, for reference, with its poorly added dual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXQKw.png)